# enhance images in dataframe panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, image

I have a dataframe.first column is image address and the second one is label. I wand to make some changes on images(for example, I want to make theimages sharper). who can I accsess to images and change it and still I have a dataframe?

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

def load_train_generator(imgs_info='/content/drive/My Drive/phd/new_data/train.xlsx',imgs_dir='/content/drive/My Drive/phd/new_data/train',
                         x_col="Image_name", y_cols="Plane", shuffle=False, batch_size=32, seed=1, target_w=256, target_h=256):

    df = pd.read_excel(imgs_info, index_col=0, engine='openpyxl')
    df["Image_name"] = df.index
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df.Image_name = imgs_dir + "/" + df.Image_name
    df.Plane.unique()
    df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    image_generator = ImageDataGenerator( rotation_range=40,  samplewise_center=False, samplewise_std_normalization=False)

    train_generator=image_generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, directory=None, x_col=x_col, y_col=y_cols, subset="training",
        batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed, shuffle=False , class_mode="categorical", target_size=(target_w, target_h))

    return train_generator, df
```

I cant write english well.  I hope it is clear...
thank you :)

```
for image_path in Valid.filepaths:
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
```

Comment: Hi, maybe this link helps you. I have a similar problem. If you find an answer, please share it.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/muhammadahmedansari/importing-images-of-different-size-shape-in-pandas

Comment: hi. do you mean to make a new dataframe?

Comment: You can create a `Lambda` layer to apply any function?

Comment: I don't  understand what you mean?

Comment: Don't want to use deep learning to do something with your image? Otherwise why are you using `ImageDataGenerator`?

Comment: I want to use it for image classification with deep learning

Comment: So you can modify the image in your pipeline after the first dense input layer with a [Lamba](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) layer

Comment: I didnt know about lamba layer and how its work.

Comment: Would you send me any link to explain lamba layer for image enhancing?

Comment: Please Corralien, If its possible, explain it to me or send me any link or URL for more information about this. Thank you 